# Issues with adding values to an array in assembly (stack smashing detected error). Also using shr with 2 registers

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm having 2 problems with my code. In my code, I'm using ecx as an int x to be converted to hex and rsi as the base address to the string with the hexadecimals that my code will generate. My first question is that I want to know how you could use the shr operation with 2 registers rather than a register and a constant. This is because I am using shr in a loop, and my code will update the register that it uses to shift the bits by. I tried doing

```
shrl %ecx, %edx
```

But it gives me an error:

```
hex_str.s:15: Error: operand type mismatch for `shr'
```

For my second question, I have some more code to share:

```
    .globl hex_str
hex_str:

# Each 4 bits of x needs to be converted to it's hex in ASCII and added to the string.
    movl $32, %ecx                              # increment (i = 8)
    movq $0xf, %r8                              # comparator (for bitwise operation)
    movq %rsi, %r9                              # address copy (so when we increment it for dereferencing we won't change the address)
loop:
    subl $4, %ecx                                   # (this way ecx starts at 28 and ends at 0) (i--)
    movl %edi, %edx                             # edx = edi
    shrl $28, %edx                              # shift by 4 * i BITS
    andq %r8, %rdx                              # edx is now the i'th group of 4 bits (we have to use r here since r8 is only r)
    addl $50, %edx                              # TRACE
    movl %edx, (%r9)                            # TRACE

    addq $4, %r9                                    # add 4 BYTES to rsi
    cmpl $0, %ecx                                   # ecx ? 0
    jle endl                                            # if ecx <= 0, return
    jmp loop                                            # else jump to loop

endl:
    ret
```

THe code is really weird, but let me just explain why it seems so dumb and inefficient. In this version I'm just tracing and seeing if it works by bypassing the error I asked in my first question, so I did shr $28, %edx rather than shrl %ecx, %edx. So at each increment, it will be shifting the 4 most significant bits of x. Then as a means of tracing, I added 50 to these so I could check to see what the resulting character is on the ASCII chart when the main program prints the values of rsi. So basically it should take the value of the 4 most significant bits, add 50 to them and add this result to each index of the string. The main function will then interppret the bits as ASCII characters and print them. Here's my result:

```
         1 = 2
        34 = 2
       819 = 2
     17476 = 2
    349525 = 2
   6710886 = 2
 125269879 = 2
  19088743 = 2
2309737967 = :
3735928559 = ?
3235822174 = >
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./x terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

As you can see, it prints the correct value once but it should be doing it 8 times, right? I think incrementing r9 and dereferencing it in subsequent loops should make it so it sets the following index to the same character again. I think it has somethjing to do with the stack smashing detected error message, but I did some looking around and couldn't find anything helpful as to what it meant. Thanks!

Edit - The stuff above is now fixed but I'm getting a seggy fault. Here's the updated code

```
    # edi contains unsigned int x to be converted
    # rsi will contain address of first byte of string to be generated


        .globl hex_str
    hex_str:

        # Each 4 bits of x needs to be converted to it's hex in ASCII and added to the string.
        movb $32, %cl                               # increment (i = 8)
        movq $0xf, %r8                              # comparator (for bitwise operation)
        movq %rsi, %r9                              # address copy (so when we increment it for dereferencing we won't change the address)
    loop:
        subl $4, %ecx                                   # (this way ecx starts at 28 and ends at 0) (i--)
        movl %edi, %edx                             # edx = edi
        shrl %cl, %edx                              # shift by 4 * i BITS (NOTE: you MUST use the 1 byte version as shr doesn't work with more than 1 byte) cl is 1 byte version of ecx
        andq %r8, %rdx                              # edx is now the i'th group of 4 bits (check notes for visual) (we have to use r here since r8 is only r)
        movb %dl, (%r9)                             # TRACE (dl is byte version of edx)

        incq %r9                                            # add 1 byte to r9 (since rsi points to a string with chars)
        cmpl $0, %ecx                                   # ecx ? 0
        jle endl                                            # if ecx <= 0, return
        jmp loop                                            # else jump to loop

    endl:
        ret
```

The cause of the seggyfault is movb dl, (r9) and inc r9, but I seriously have no idea why. Shouldnt this just put the contents in the dereference of the address r9, and then increment r9 by 1 so it can add the next byte to the next index of r9? I'm really confused. Thanks!!

Comment: Intel 8-bit legacy braindamage\*: variable shift instructions have their shift count in `cl`. Not `cx`, not `ch`, not `ecx`, nor `rcx`. \* given that the shift amount is modulo-reduced, it doesn't matter all that much, but it is ugly.

Comment: @EOF as a fun aside, on µarchs that allow separate renaming of 8bit regs the dependency really is on `cl`, while for the `shrx` family it's on the whole register. So they act differently (timing difference, of course the result is the same) around writes to `ch`.

Comment: I just did this and the problem is fixed, thanks! I'm getting a new problem though, so if you are still interested in helping I updated the post, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "count" argument of Intel shift operations must be 8 bits, either an immediate or %cl. You can't use the full 32-bit register.

The stack smashing problem seems like it might be in the calling code, not in this. (After all, you're assuming that on entry, %rsi points to a buffer that's at least 32 bytes. Perhaps it isn't.)

A couple of additional comments on your experimental code: it seems to me you'll be computing the same number 8 times and appending all 8 copies as 32-bit integers to the buffer. I'm not sure what your actual intentions were, perhaps you should have shifted %edi left 4 bits on every iteration. As for your printing problem, I can only guess that maybe your printing routine expected 8-bit characters, not 32-bit integers, as input?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't generally use all the bits, but the argument itself must be 8 bits.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this got rid of my original errors. The other issue was that I was assuming that the array from rsi was 4 bytes per index, but it was actually 1 (it's a string). I've updated my code and now this is my problem, I replaced  the following lines:

movl %edx, (%r9) 

addq $4, %r9

with this:

 movb %dl, (%r9)  

 incq %r9

THese are the cause of the segmentation fault and I'm not sure why. I always replaced ecx with cl like you said, and that seems to be working

Comment: It doesn't really translate well in comments so I'll post the full updated code in the question, thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: And yes to answer your question about the earlier code I was planning on just appending the same number 8 times just to see if it was properly adding any bytes at all to the arrays, just as a means of tracing. When I finish the function I'll update it so it appends the right stuff to the array which is meant to be the hexadecimal of the number x. The updated code should probably make more sense too, since now I know how to shift with registers

Comment: You're storing $32 in %cl, without clearing the high bits of %ecx. But at the end of the loop, you're still comparing all of %ecx with 0.

Comment: @rcgldr: modern x86 masks the shift count to 5 bits for any operand-size less than 64 bits.  i.e. you can zero an 8 or 16-bit register with `shr $17, %ax`.  Note the start of the Operation section [in Intel's insn ref manual for `shr`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/SAL_SAR_SHL_SHR).  Also the text description agrees with that, saying only masked to 5 bits.  The manual also specifically says that 286 masks the count to 5 bits, but it's possible that's wrong and maybe 286 did mask the shift count to 0-15.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I deleted my prior comment. Max count for 80286 is 31 bits, so a 5 bit mask for cpu >= 80286, and 6 bits for 64 bit registers. The articles I found note that the masking of the shift count started with the 80286. The 8088/8086 and 80186, will shift up to 255 times even though it's pointless, unless used for a delay instruction.

Comment: @rcgldr: Yup, that's exactly what Intel's ISA reference manual says, so everything is in agreement.  Same for rotate instructions, too.  `bts reg` and BMI2 `shlx` and so on also mask the same way as rotate by `cl`.  The one exception is that [SIMD shift instructions like `psrld`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/PSRLW_PSRLD_PSRLQ) *saturate* the count, so you can zero a register with them.  AVX512-VBMI2 double-shift `vpshldv` is going to *mask* the count with only `&31`, though, so it can't shift "all the way": https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/752417